# SelectLayerByAttribute_management not selecting anything

Tags: arcpy, select-by-attribute, feature-layer

I've read through most of the other similar questions and nothing so far has addressed my issue; most are about syntax.

I'm trying to select by attribute from a Feature Layer. But every time, Arc announces that it succeeded and nothing is selected. It works just fine using the same expression to select from a Table View. Any ideas?

```
expression = arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(tempFeatureLayer, "BLDG_ID") + " LIKE '{0}%'".format(county)

arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(tempFeatureLayer, "NEW_SELECTION", expression)
if int(arcpy.GetCount_management(tempFeatureLayer)[0]) > 0:
    arcpy.DeleteRows_management(tempFeatureLayer)
```

It's an SDE Database feature class, if that makes a difference.

I've also tried rewriting the expression as below with the same result:

```
expression = """ "BLDG_ID" LIKE '37019%'"""
```

and

```
expression = "BLDG_ID LIKE '37019%'"
```

Comment: It's a text field.

Comment: Try: `expression = "{0} LIKE '{1}%'".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(tempFeatureLayer, "BLDG_ID"), county)`

Comment: Nope. Still selects nothing. If I use this expression on a Table View, however, it will select all the records like it's supposed to. It's only with a Feature Layer that it doesn't work.

Comment: MakeFeatureLayer_management.  I've tried UpdateCursor the above is my second attempt to find a way to delete these rows without having to go in SQL Server.  The database will not allow UpdateCursor outside of an active Edit session. Staring an edit session crashes Arc.

Comment: And GetCount etc. of the feature layer is not empty? Maybe you can use [ArcSDESQLExecute](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-classes/arcsdesqlexecute.htm), I have not tried it.

Comment: GetCount prior to SelectLayerByAttribute results in 5+ million records. After selection is 0 records. I'll look into  ArcSDESQLExecute.

Comment: Do you have misplaced double quotes in your expression examples? See if this works: `fieldname = 'BLDG_ID'` `findVal = '37019%'` `expression = '"' + fieldname + '" LIKE ' + "'" + findVal + "'"`

Comment: It only appears to be an issue if the Feature Layer is created in the same database that the original Feature Class is in. Using the same bit of code on a Feature Layer referencing a Feature Class that exists in a different database works just fine. I'm going to guess it's a bug. I used BERA's suggestion to use ArcSDESQLExecute as a work around.